# Mount USB-Device (Printer) per Script on Ubuntu 14.04 Virtual Box 4.33

Tags: ubuntu, usb, virtualbox, printer, shell-script

We have ubuntu 14.04 with Windows7 on the Virtual Box 4.33 running. As the USB-Printer is mounted at the host or the guest and there seems to be no solution to make it on both available, now my opinion was to create a script. The script should switch the mounting of the USB-Port from the printer to the virtual box or the host.

I searched for such a solution, but google didn't help. Isn't that possible?
Any Idea for such a solution.

Thanks for any help!